# Method changed string values are not showing up in data-bound textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml

So I have a class and a form.
The class hosts the MySQL code and the form holds the events that trigger the code in the MySQL class

```
// Code that acceses the class
// This triggers a method that is supposed to get the next record from the database.
private void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Tag.text is the auto incremented unique record number.
        // The MySQL code is meant to get the next record ahead of the number in tag.text
        // in the corresponding table field.
        usersMysql.RegForm_Next(tag.Text);
    }
```

this next part is the method that accesses the MySQL code meant to fetch the next record

```
public void RegForm_Next(string tag_Value)
    {
        // tagValue now holds the number, which was in tag.text in the previous page, as a string
        // tagValue has already been predeclared as a string
        tagValue = tag_Value;
        // Navigation is the method that holds the MySQL code.
        // By passing "Forward", the method has a code to tell from that, which query to excecute.
        Navigation("Forward");
    }
```

The next code is the MySQL code meant to fetch the record

```
// Command to go to the next or previous rexord
    public void Navigation(string scroll)
    {

        if (scroll == "Forward")
        {
            query = "select * from temp.signup where tag = (select min(tag) from temp.signup where tag > '" + tagValue + "' );";
        }
        if (scroll ==  "Backward")
        {
            query = "select * from temp.signup where tag = (select max(tag) from temp.signup where tag < '" + tagValue + "' );";
        }

        //Database connection parameters
        string sqlcon = "datasource = " + datasource + ";" + "port=" + port + ";" + "username=" + username + ";" + "password=" + password + ";";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);

        MySqlDataReader rdr;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

        //Excecution
        try
        {
            //If the connection is Open
            con.Open();
            {
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    // Declarations
                    // All these strings have been declared under the public class declaration.
                    sid = GetString(rdr, "id");
                    stag = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, "tag");

                    sfirst = GetString(rdr, "first");
                    sfourth = GetString(rdr, "surname");

                    sdob = rdr.GetString("dob");
                    ssex = rdr.GetString("sex");

                    susername = GetString(rdr, "username");
                    spassword = GetString(rdr, "password");

                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "SQL related error: Nav", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

    }
```

Now this where the problem comes in. I need to bind the strings values to textboxes back in the previous page that called the method in the MySQL class up.

```
// This is how the ID binding was set up for example.
// This is where sid was declared.
string sid;
public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return sid;
        }

        set
        {
            sid = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }
```

And this is how the textbox binding was set up

```
<TextBox x:Name="id" Text="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Margin="158,46,453,468" FontSize="13" TabIndex="1" />
```

I've set the data context in the page wit the textboxes but the strings are never loaded back into the textbox

```
public registrationForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        usersMysql = new users.MySQL.usersMySQL();
        DataContext = usersMysql;
    }
```

I can confirm that the strings are being loaded. I've tested with a message box. But nothing shows up in the text boxes.

This is the function I use for "propertyChanged" in the class

```
//Property changed
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

If I bind two textBoxes to the same public string, they reflect what is being typed in the other.  Where am I going wrong then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is changing the `sid` backing field, not the `ID` property.

Therefore, the `PropertyChanged` event is never fired, and WPF never finds out about the change.

Comment: Now I just feel plain stupid. I'm surprised no-one has down voted this yet. Thanks a bunch.